# Active Directory - Migrate objects from Win Server 2003 R2 to Win Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2003, active-directory, migration

I am about to migrate some users and objects from a domain managed by Win Server 2003 to a domain managed by Win Server 2008 R2.

I heard about AD migration tools, but **are there issues concerning domains schemas or AD and Win server versions ? What about users credentials (will they be moved seamlessly ?)**

Comment: What do you mean by migrate? How are these two Domains able to migrate are they the same Domain just two DC's or are they in a  domain trust? etc?

Comment: This should probably be moved to Server Fault.  Anyway, do you mean that you are using ADMT or are you using some other third-party tool?

Comment: MS has the information you seek: [ADMT Guide: Migrating and Restructuring Active Directory Domains](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc974332(v=ws.10).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this tool - LDIFDE, you can export and import users and objects

[LDIFDE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555636)